# How to remove Scroll Bar From Home Page

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I am working in Wordpress, using the widgets for making the Homepage and while making the site responsive there is Scroll Bar coming which is due to some text unformatting. How can I remove the Scrollbar from the Homepage.

Comment: Can You please give the code in CSS.

Comment: please give link to your site

Comment: Why do you need Link to my site??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done in CSS by setting `overflow: hidden;` on the `body` tag.